# How to change font of arabic numerals as markers in matplotlib scatter plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have arabic numerals as markers on my scatter plot. Till this point I have been able to get following code template:

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(20,20,marker ='o', s=20*2**5, facecolors='r',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.75)
plt.scatter(20,20,c='k',marker="$"+str(5)+"$",s=5*2**5)
```

This generates following figure:
[image]

But I am not happy with the font. I want a font similar to that of numbers displayed along the axes. Can anyone suggest a solution/an alternative?

Comment: Could you change the the question. It is misleading since you already know how to plot Arabic numbers as markers.

Comment: @gabra Thanks for suggesting the change. I've incorporated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution that uses TeX backend, if you are fine with that:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [
       r'\usepackage{sansmath}',
       r'\sansmath'
]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(20,20,marker ='o', s=20*2**5, facecolors='r',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.75)
plt.scatter(20,20,c='k',marker="$5$",s=5*2**5,edgecolors='none')
plt.text(21, 20, '5', fontsize=16)
plt.xlim(19, 22)
plt.savefig('t.png')
```

[image]

Note that:

- I added `edgecolors='none'` to the second `scatter()` call, otherwise the number appears bold.
- Sadly, a custom marker has to be specified inside `$$`, and `\sansmath` has to appear before math mode. Therefore the switch to sans math is global.

It is possible to make `\mathsf` work locally in the math mode with `lualatex` backend, but then you'd have a problem with making the tick labels sans serif (although if you just need the same style, making both tick labels and markers serif will be easy).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.